# write a query to remove 4 first letters on special records in sqlite

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

My original code is :

```
 c = mydb.rawQuery("select dId,dWord FROM german where dWord like '%" + search + "%'", null);
```

and it returned complete records like below photo.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueVbF.jpg)

I changed code to follow code but it also had problem .

```
c = mydb.rawQuery("select dId, case when substr(dWord, 1, 4) in ('das ', 'der ','die ') then substr(dWord, 5, length(dWord) - 4) else dWord end as dWord from german where dWord like '%"+search+"%'",null);
```

It doesn't show 4 letters and it is good, but it shows the records that had this prefix( 'das ', 'der ','die ') and it shouldn't be like this. It must return records just contain searched characters . In photo you can see it returned records that had prefix .[All these words started with 'das '](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBJS1.jpg) 
whit search 'das 'after second code it should returned words that contains das on their main body not on removed prefix . I hope I could explain it clearly .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite the concatenation operator is `||` and not `+`.
Also don't concatenate directly the parameter `search` but use a `?` placeholder and pass `search` at the 2nd argument of `rawQuery()`. This is the safe way to avoid [sql-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
String sql = "select dId, " + 
   "case when substr(dWord, 1, 4) in ('das ', 'der ','die ') " + 
   "then substr(dWord, 5) else dWord end as dWord " +
   "from german where dWord like '%' || ? || '%'";
c = mydb.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {search});
```

If that `dWord` column in the `WHERE` clause is the result of the `CASE` expression then change the statement to this:

```
String sql = "select t.* from (select dId, " + 
   "case when substr(dWord, 1, 4) in ('das ', 'der ','die ') " + 
   "then substr(dWord, 5) else dWord end as dWord " +
   "from german) t where t.dWord like '%' || ? || '%' " +
   "order by instr(t.dWord, ?), t.dWord"
c = mydb.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {search, search});
```

Comment: Thanks but,it didn't change anything and it returned records like first photo .

Comment: The code works. Check this simplified demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pxtR4jq4AJ8R8zvveu2GoT/1 I can't tell how you use it in your code.

Comment: Also this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pxtR4jq4AJ8R8zvveu2GoT/2 for search pattern `'das '`

Comment: Clarify something: *it should returned words that contains das on their main body not on removed prefix* does this mean that the search pattern is for the remaining part of the dWord after the removal of the 4 characters?

Comment: My English is not so good and I can not explain it very well . I tried to explain with example . I have these words on my data base : 
1- das apartment 
2- das Gluck 
3- die Hand 
4- dashboard
5- dasselbe
6- alandas
7-dermatologe
8-irmander
9-trandie
10 - der tisch

and after run query and filter these words ('das') it should show this records :
1- dashboard
2- dasselbe
3- alandas

or if I filter ('der') :
1- irmander

Comment: This is what my 2nd query does. Check the demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pxtR4jq4AJ8R8zvveu2GoT/3

Comment: is it possible to sort returned data based on searched characters ? for example if I searched for 'ap' then in returned data at first it show records that  started with 'ap' and then records that 'ap' is in the middle of word because I want to use it for dictionary .eg :
search input : 'ap'
result :
Apartment
Apollo
apin
rap
kapeloo
....

Comment: Thanks a lot .It is work but it didn't sorted word alphabetically .eg :
searched 'ap'
apartment
apbrment
apcrment

Comment: I edited to sort alphbetically **after** the 1st sorting.

Comment: In Apartment Apollo apin rap kapeloo the results are not sorted alphabetically though.

Comment: I am a little dumb , sorry for it and thank you very much :))))

Comment: I asked new question about make this code no case sensitive on follow link . Maybe you can help . Thanks :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58874356/how-to-make-my-sqlite-query-case-insensitive/