# how to make my SQlite query case insensitive?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

My original code is :

```
String sql = "select t.* from (select dId, " +
                    "case when substr(dWord, 1, 4) in ('das ', 'der ','die ') " +
                    "then substr(dWord, 5) else dWord end as dWord " +
                    "from german) t where t.dWord like '%' || ? || '%' " +
                    "order by instr(t.dWord, ?), t.dWord";
            c = mydb.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {search, search});
```

For example when I searched 'A'  it show all word stared with Capital 'A' sorted alphabetically and then show words started with 'a' alphabetically. But I want to consider 'a' as 'A' and 'A' as 'a'.What should I change on my code?
Edit1 = I know COLLATE NOCASE but i don't know how I use it on my code .

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973541/how-to-set-sqlite3-to-be-case-insensitive-when-string-comparing

Comment: Hi 
I know COLLATE NOCASE but I don't know where I should add it on my code to it works properly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last line of the statement to:

```
order by instr(lower(t.dWord), lower(?)), lower(t.dWord)
```

The function `lower()` will convert both the column value and the search string to lower case, to simulate case insensitive comparison inside the function `instr()`.

Comment: Thanks alot . Is it possible to changed a code for consider these letters as similar letter also.example :
'a' as 'a' and 'ä' | 'ä' as 'ä' and 'a'
And also for bellow letters as explained example .
o/ö - 
u/ü - 
ss/ß -

Comment: SQLite is not that flexible at this issue. There are many questions here in SO about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492508/ignore-accents-sqlite3, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2841694/how-to-sql-compare-columns-when-one-has-accented-chars, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58874356/how-to-make-my-sqlite-query-case-insensitive/58876037?noredirect=1#comment104039856_58876037,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16282083/how-to-ignore-accent-in-sqlite-query-android, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906086/problems-ordering-sqlite-by-a-column-with-accented-characters-Á

Comment: Maybe you can help on this case?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59702535/how-to-write-sqlite-query-to-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Use the lower or upper keyword in the column you wanna oder by without case sensitive

```
SELECT NAME from Customers 
order By lower(NAME);
```

Reference

[SQLite lower](https://www.w3resource.com/sqlite/core-functions-lower.php#:~:targetText=SQLite%20lower()%20converts%20all,works%20for%20ASCII%20characters%20only.&targetText=A%20string%20whose%20characters%20are%20going%20to%20be%20converted%20to%20lowercase.)